# push data into an array with pair values

Tags: javascript, arrays

how can I push data into an array in js if it's type is likw this... d= [[label, value]]. At first I want to push the label data then the values.... 
I get the data from an xml file.
If I had only a simple array I used the simple variable.push sintax.
Will varialble[][0].push or variable[][1].push work

Comment: hey i know this is kind of late, but you can simply use array.push({ key : value }); and access it arr[index][key] and it will post the value, you can also do pairs of pairs using this method....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe you would be better of using an object,

So you could do

```
var d  = {
"Label" : "Value"
};
```

And to add the value you could

```
d.label = "value";
```

This might be a more structured approach and easier to understand if your arrays become big. And if you build the JSON valid it's easy to make a string and parse it back in.

Like  `var stringD = JSON.stringify(d);  var parseD = JSON.parse(stringD);`

UPDATE - ARRAY 2D

This is how you could declare it

```
var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];

alert(items[0][0]);
```

And the alert is reading from it,

To add things to it you would say `items[0][0] = "Label" ; items[0][1] = "Value";`

If you want to do all the labels then all the values do...

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < labelssize; i ++)
{
  items[i][0] = labelhere;
}


for(var i = 0 ; i < labelssize; i ++)
{
  items[i][1] = valuehere;
}
```

Comment: Updated for 2D arrays hope this helps

Comment: thanks... the problem is that I don't know how many values this array will have... I get the data from an xml file... first I get the labels... than the values....

Comment: thats fine you dont have to predinfe the size of the array anyway

Comment: So just add every label e.g. for loop items[i][0] until its complete then the same for loop but itmes[i][1]

Answer (score 15):

You could do like this:

```
var d = [];
d.push([label, value]);
```

Comment: the problem is that I get the data from an xml and I don't know how many values. first I get the labels... then I want to push the values

Comment: @AndreiIon Could you post your expected result?

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a an array of objects.

Imagine this sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Your data structure could be:

```
var catalog = array(
  { 
    'id': 'bk101',
    'author': 'Gambardella, Matthew',
    'title': 'XML Developer\'s Guide',
    'genre': 'Computer'
  },
  {
    'id': 'bk102',
    'author': 'Ralls, Kim',
    'title': 'Midnight Rain',
    'genre': 'fantasy'
  }
);
```

Then, you can acces the data like an array. Sample operations:

**Read value:**

```
var genre = catalog[0]['genre'];
```

**Add a new property:**

```
catalog[1]['price'] = '15.50';
```

**List all titles:**

```
for (var i=0; i<catalog.length; i++) {
  console.log(catalog[i]['title'];
}
```